# send2trash not working with tkinter filedialog

Tags: python

I am trying to send a file to the trash using send2trash. Used like `send2trash("C:\\path\\to\\file\\file.txt")` works correctly but when using `filedialog.askopenfilename()` and feeding the results in to it doesn't. I have tried using `str()` to no avail.

Code:

```
m = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Choose which file to shred",filetypes=[("file","*.*")])
send2trash(m) #Also used send2trash(str(m)) but that did not work
```

Error:

```
  File "c:\Python310\Scripts\delete.py", line 293, in <module>
    send2trash(str(m))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\send2trash\plat_win_legacy.py", line 115, in send2trash
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\send2trash\plat_win_legacy.py", line 115, in <listcomp>
    paths = [get_short_path_name(path) for path in paths]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\send2trash\plat_win_legacy.py", line 99, in get_short_path_name
    raise WindowsError(err_no, FormatError(err_no), long_path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the file specified.: '\\\\?\\C:/Python310/Scripts/testfile.txt'
```

I don't know why this isn't working so any help is very much appreciated.

Python 3.10.4, Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very new to python but I think send2trash only accepts backslashes in pathname and looking at the error 'askopenfilename' is returning path using forward slashes

```
m = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Choose which file to shred",filetypes=[("file","*.*")])
m = m.replace('/', '\\')
send2trash(m)
```